# Google cloud sql - Storage size reset

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, cost-management

I am using google console and I earlier had 2.5 TB of data in my DB and hence the auto increase configuration of GCP increased the storage to 2.73 TB. So I am being billed for 2.73 TB storage.

Recently I have reduced the storage size of my database to 1.5 TB. Even now I am being billed for 2.73 TB storage.

I am trying to reduce the storage max provisioned to 1.7 TB. I also wanted to have Automatic increase enabled so that in future if the data grows, the size gets incremented. I am wondering if I can set the value to some thing around 1.7 TB so that I am not billed more.

Currently I am being billed for close to 1.2 TB extra storage which increased in the past. The docs says $0.17/GB. So I will be saving some cost here.

[Screeenshot for the current configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAPX2.png)

My concern is that

1. If I decrease will the DB restart? If yes, how long will it take?
2. Is it depending on the data size that I have? If yes, what is the forecast for 1.5 TB storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot decrease allocated storage space on Google Cloud SQL.

One manual method is to export the databases, delete and create a new instance, and then import your data.

Reference documentation:

[About instance settings](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings)